# Network interfaces gone after first boot, keyboard not working in IPMI Remote Control

Tags: ubuntu, ipmi, supermicro

I can install Ubuntu 10.10 and 10.04.2 through Supermicro IPMI remote console just fine but after the installer finishes and system reboots, the keyboard does not work through Remote Console window. The physical keyboard attached to the server itself works though.

I can access all the server's BIOS setups (motherboard, raid, nic) through remote console but as soon as Ubuntu takes over, it does not work.

We tried some other bootable cd's and with them the remote console window keyboard works. Even when installing Windows OS we can use the remote keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that this Ubuntu installation has been installed by pressing F4 at the very first screen during the install and choosing *Install a minimal virtual machine*. Probably due to a habit of installing it usually on virtual machines :-).

Because of that fact, network intefaces can be inaccessible, remote keyboarding (through IPMIviewer or similar [iKVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28iKVM.29)) and booting system without the help of installation CD (by using the *Boot from the hard disk* option) might not work.

The solutions are the following:

1. Reinstall without *minimal virtual machine* mode, or
2. If you have a working network connection then

   ```
   aptitude install linux-image-server
   reboot
   ```

   If you don't then first open the **/etc/fstab** file and add this line:

   ```
   /dev/cdrom /cdrom iso9660
   ```

   Then insert the installation CD (if its not already in) and type the following commands:

   ```
   mount /cdrom
   mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
   apt-cdrom add cdrom
   aptitude update
   aptitude install linux-image-server
   reboot
   ```

   This will mount the CD disc, make it the only package repository and install a kernel that has support for more than just a handful of vmware/xen/*etc* virtual devices.

   After you get it working, restore /etc/apt/sources.list file from the backup and update aptitude again.